# Using REST API, Oauth in php

Tags: php, json, api, rest, oauth

I create a mobile website with registration form. They gave me the REST API member service to POST data from my mobile registration form. All I know is send the data to email address using PHP.

How to use the REST API in php?

I also need to validate if the email address is existing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have any PHP form sample source code that uses REST API that sends the data to the main website's database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your PHP REST client take a look at [HTTPFUL](http://phphttpclient.com/). It is a very lightweight PHP library that provides a lot of the functions you need for writing REST clients (i.e. making HTTP requests, setting headers, authentication etc.). It is much easier than low level libraries like cURL.

The validation of the email address should normally be handled by the REST server. This means when you POST your data from your registration form and the email has already been taken, the server should send an appropriate response, i.e. status code 409 Conflict or something like that. Alternatively it may provide a special request you could send upfront to check the email. It really depends on the REST Api you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I had this documentation and I can't identify which error code is for email validation. I would like to send you the documentation to see whether its in there or not. mjdiamzon@panasianventures.com

Comment: Usually there will be no single status code for email validation. Most HTTP status codes can have multiple reasons and it is up to the API developer to provide further information in the response body that indicates what is happening.